# How to get list of all defined keyboard shortcuts in "react-hotkeys-hook" so I can display help dialog?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I've been using "react-hotkeys-hook" to register hotkeys in my web app. Since there are many shortcuts, I would like to know how to get list of all of them so that I can display them in the help page.
I can see that "react-hotkeys" provides the `getApplicationKeyMap()`, but is there something similar in case of the hooks version of the package?

Answer (score 1):

There is not. The reasons for that are described here: https://github.com/JohannesKlauss/react-hotkeys-hook/issues/255#issuecomment-683320260

In short, this would reverse the source of truth. Since you need to know every combination beforehand anyways, there is really no need for the hook to keep track of all hotkeys over the application.

If you feel that this would be a useful feature, please open up a ticket in the Github repo: https://github.com/JohannesKlauss/react-hotkeys-hook/issues/new